# How to update content type in sharepoint 2013 by remote provising?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

Using vs i create site column and content type and added that content type to the list now i added new site column to the same content type and deploying the solution but content is not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an event receiver on your feature and manually update the columns using the FeatureActivated-event